# Intel Virtualization Technology, HAXM cannot be installed

Tags: android, windows, virtual, virtualization

I was working on my android project like 2 hours ago with the emulator so good, but I dont know what happened, it said that the emulator could not be opened because of the HAXM was not installed, so what i did was to remove but when i wanted to re-install it, there was a message error and it was this:

[image]

So after reading some posts here, I was trying to disable and enable from BIOS, and i found out that when i disable it it shows that and when i want to install it, obviously it will show that it is turned off.
[image]

when i enable it it seems that there is no virtualization, which is wierd and when trying to install it:
[image]

can someone help me out please? i could appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these steps:

- Open *Control Panel*
- Open *Programs and Features*.
- Click on *Turn Windows features on and off*.
- Uncheck *Hyper-V* option and restart your computer.

After that you should be able to install HAXM

Comment: Thanks, it worked. could you explain me what could happened? and what is the difference between Hyper V and VT-x, do you know what is the best size of memory for the emulator(4GB)?

Comment: [Hyper-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) is a Microsoft's virtualization system. You can't have Hyper-V and HAXM enabled at the same time, for this reason HAXM didn't install. The best size of the RAM depends on how much ram you have on your system, there isn't a right or a wrong size.